# How to hide some html elements if client resolution is lower?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with 5 `<tr>` elements and it looks good on my 1920x1080 screen but it looks really bad on lower resolutions.

The code is the following:

```
<table class="table fullwidth nextevent_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row1 open">
            <td valign="middle" align="center" width="44">
                <a href="/index.php/Calendar/Calendarevent/1.html?">
                    <img src="/icons/events/35.png" style="max-height: 40px;" alt="eventicon3" class="eventicon eventicon">
                </a>
            </td>
        <tr class="row1 open">
            <td valign="middle" align="center" width="44">
                <a href="/index.php/Calendar/Calendarevent/2.html?">
                    <img src="/icons/events/35.png" style="max-height: 40px;" alt="eventicon3" class="eventicon eventicon">
                </a>
            </td>
        <tr class="row1 open">
            <td valign="middle" align="center" width="44">
                <a href="/index.php/Calendar/Calendarevent/3.html?">
                    <img src="/icons/events/35.png" style="max-height: 40px;" alt="eventicon3" class="eventicon eventicon">
                </a>
            </td>
        <tr class="row1 open">
            <td valign="middle" align="center" width="44">
                <a href="/index.php/Calendar/Calendarevent/4.html?">
                    <img src="/icons/events/35.png" style="max-height: 40px;" alt="eventicon3" class="eventicon eventicon">
                </a>
            </td>
        <tr class="row1 open">
            <td valign="middle" align="center" width="44">
                <a href="/index.php/Calendar/Calendarevent/5.html?">
                    <img src="/icons/events/35.png" style="max-height: 40px;" alt="eventicon3" class="eventicon eventicon">
                </a>
            </td>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It's possible with PHP or javascript to, for example:

If a user has a 1440x900 screen, hide the last `<tr>`

If a user has a 1280x1024 screen, hide the 2 last `<tr>`

Thanks!

Comment: FYI your HTML is invalid; you're missing all your `</tr>` tags.

Comment: You can use media queries to hide `tr` based on resolutions. Simpler and much more reliable than JS. See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24378398/2513751

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS media queries for this:

```
@media (max-width: 1440px) {
    .nextevent_table tr:last-child { 
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    .nextevent_table tr:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm!! Thank you so much!